# The best practice to reuse knockout model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a base knockout model to work with lists, with common functionality (paging, sorting, etc.):

ListViewModel.js:

```
function ListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Items = ko.observableArray();
    // other props and methods
}

return ListViewModel;
```

Now, I want to reuse (inherit) this model for concrete class UsersListViewModel. What the best way (acceptence to knockout) to do it? Create ListViewModel inside UsersListViewModel, or extend ListViewModel with the new field and methods?

Now i've created a ListViewModel object inside UsersListViewModel, but i don't like this:

UsersListViewModel:

```
 function UsersListViewModel(model) {
      var self = this;

      self.List = new ListViewModel();
      self.IsInitialized = ko.observable(false);
 }

 return UsersListViewModel;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past, when we had to do something like this, we just used apply (http://jsfiddle.net/85TeD/1/):

```
function UsersListViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    ListViewModel.apply(self);

    self.OtherProp = ko.observable("other");

}
```

If you want to implement full classical inheritance, this is a start: http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Comment: Does apply copy all the observable to the passed reference?

Comment: @Nish Yup, it should create properties on UsersListViewModel for all properties declared on ListViewModel